# How to hide query or population columns in datagridview ms access according to the user in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I want to hide the population columns in DataGridView ms access according to the user name.

if username : "User" then all columns appear, if username : "Admin" then the column "VALUEINV" does not appear or hide and if username : "Owner" then the column "QTY" does not appear or hide.

Another one if I run debug in my visual studio then I close Form2 doesn't stop debugging so I have to do stop debugging from visual studio if there is anything wrong with my code.

Thanks

```
'code in form1
    Private Sub LOGIN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LOGIN.Click
 Dim scn As New OleDbConnection()
        scn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Login.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;"
        Dim scmd As New OleDbCommand("select count (*) as cnt from login_database where username=@usr and password=@pwd", scn)
        scmd.Parameters.Clear()
        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr", txt_UserName.Text)
        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", txt_PWD.Text)
        scn.Open()
        If scmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString() = "1" Then
            Dim grantedPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "granted.jpg")
            PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(grantedPath)
            MessageBox.Show("YOU ARE GRANTED WITH ACCESS")
            With Form2
                .lblEmployeeName.Text = "Welcome, " & txt_UserName.Text
                .Show()
            End With
            Me.Visible = False
        End If
        scn.Close()
    End Sub
```

```
'code in form2
 Private WithEvents dt As New DataTable
    Dim cn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Login.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;"
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            dt = New DataTable
            Dim query = "select INVONO,QTY,VALUEINV from Sales"
            Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(query, cn.ToString)
                adapter.Fill(dt)
            End Using
            Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
            Me.DataGridView1.Refresh()
        Catch myerror As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

I tried with code but it didn't work. Maybe someone can provide a solution to me

Comment: *"if username : "User" then all columns appear, if username : "Admin" then the column "VALUEINV" does not appear or hide and if username : "Owner" then the column "QTY" does not appear or hide"*. If only VB had a keyword that would work the same way "if" does in that sentence. Hang on a minute!

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? You want to manage display of columns on Form2? Pass username to form and build an If Then Else block. Perhaps with a globally declared variable that can be seen across forms.